# Hackerrank's Merging Communities

Tags: java, algorithm

Challenge can be found [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/merging-communities)

> People connect with each other in a social network. A connection
>   between Person I and Person J is represented as M I J. When two persons
>   belonging to different communities connect, the net effect is the
>   merger of both communities which I and J belongs to.
>
> At the beginning, there are N people representing N communities. Suppose
>   person 1 and 2 connected and later 2 and 3 connected, then 1,2, and 3 will
>   belong to the same community.
>
> There are two type of queries:
>
> M I J => communities containing person I and J merged (if they belong to
>   different communities).
>
> Q I => print the size of the community to which person  belongs.
>
> Input Format
>
> The first line of input will contain integers N and Q, i.e. the number
>   of people and the number of queries. The next Q lines will contain the
>   queries.
>
> Constraints :
>
> 1 <= N <= 100000
>
> 1 <= Q <= 200000

My code times out for 6 / 9 test-cases, so obviously this can be improved a lot.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = s.nextInt();
        int Q = s.nextInt();
        DisjointSet ds = new DisjointSet();

        for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            ds.makeSet(i);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < Q; i++) {
            int command = s.next().charAt(0);
            if(command == 'Q') {
                System.out.println(ds.getSetSize(s.nextInt()));
            } else {
                ds.union(s.nextInt(), s.nextInt());
            }
        }
    }
}


class DisjointSet {
    private List<Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>> disjointSet;

    DisjointSet() {
        disjointSet = new ArrayList<Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>>();
    }

    public void makeSet(int element) {
        Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(element);
        map.put(element, set);
        disjointSet.add(map);
    }

    public void union(int a, int b) {
        int first = find(a);
        int second = find(b);
        Set<Integer> firstSet = null;
        Set<Integer> secondSet = null;

        for(int i = 0; i < disjointSet.size(); i++) {
            Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = disjointSet.get(i);
            if(map.containsKey(first)) {
                firstSet = map.get(first);
            } else if(map.containsKey(second)) {
                secondSet = map.get(second);
            }
        }

        if(firstSet != null && secondSet != null) {
            firstSet.addAll(secondSet);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < disjointSet.size(); i++) {
            Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = disjointSet.get(i);
            if (map.containsKey(first)) {
                map.put(first, firstSet);
            } else if (map.containsKey(second)) {
                map.remove(second);
                disjointSet.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public int find(int n) {
        for(int i = 0; i < disjointSet.size(); i++) {
            Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = disjointSet.get(i);
            Set<Integer> keySet = map.keySet();
            for(Integer key : keySet) {
                Set<Integer> set = map.get(key);
                if(set.contains(n)) {
                    return key;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int getSetSize(int n) {
        for(int i = 0; i < disjointSet.size(); i++) {
            Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = disjointSet.get(i);
            Set<Integer> keySet = map.keySet();
            for(Integer key : keySet) {
                Set<Integer> set = map.get(key);
                if(set.contains(n)) {
                    return set.size();
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try researching disjoint sets, [for example here on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)?  If you just follow one of the examples there, your program should easily pass the time limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Simplifying

> ```
>         for(int i = 0; i < disjointSet.size(); i++) {
>             Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = disjointSet.get(i);
>             if(map.containsKey(first)) {
>                 firstSet = map.get(first);
>             } else if(map.containsKey(second)) {
>                 secondSet = map.get(second);
>             }
>         }
> ```

Consider instead

```
        for (Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map : disjointSet) {
            if (firstSet == null) {
                firstSet = map.get(first);
            }

            if (secondSet == null) {
                secondSet = map.get(second);
            }

            if (firstSet != null && secondSet != null) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

You don't need `i`.  Java can iterate over a collection directly, which saves us a line of code.

You don't need to check `containsKey` before doing `get`.  If `containsKey` is `false`, then `get` will return `null`.

You might as well stop as soon as both sets are found.  You don't need to keep going.

A linear scan over all the values is something like \$\mathcal{O}(N \cdot Q)\$, assuming the number of merges is proportional to the number of queries.  Because you have to do one linear scan for each merge.  However, there is an alternative solution that is closer to \$\mathcal{O}(Q)\$.

#### Alternative data structure

> ```
>         DisjointSet ds = new DisjointSet();
> ```

Consider

```
        DisjointSet ds = new DisjointSet(N + 1);
```

Now you can change from

> ```
>     private List<Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>> disjointSet;
> ```

to something fixed size.  The normal representation for a [disjoint set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) is a [parent pointer tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parent_pointer_tree) with ranks added.  In this case, we need to track the sizes and can use those to represent the rank.  Consider

```
public class DisjointSet {

    private int[] parents;
    private int[] sizes;

    DisjointSet(int N) {
        parents = new int[N];
        sizes = new int[N];
    }

    public void makeSet(int i) {
        parents[i] = i;
        sizes[i] = 1;
    }

    public void union(int a, int b) {
        int first = find(a);
        int second = find(b);

        // if already part of the same set, no need to union
        if (first == second) {
            return;
        }

        if (sizes[first] < sizes[second]) {
            parents[first] = second;
            sizes[second] += sizes[first];
        } else {
            parents[second] = first;
            sizes[first] += sizes[second];
        }
    }

    public int find(int i) {
        // if not the root
        if (parents[i] != i) {
            // Make the parent the root, so that it will recurse at most once
            // on subsequent calls.
            parents[i] = find(parents[i]);
        }

        // Return the root (as the parent is always the root by this point).
        return parents[i];
    }

    public int getSetSize(int i) {
        return sizes[find(parents[i])];
    }

}
```

The `parents` array stores the immediate parent of any element.  If an element is alone in a set, it is its own parent.  Root nodes (terminators) are also their own parents.

For a root node, the `sizes` array holds the size of the set.  For other nodes, it holds junk data.

This uses both union-by-rank and path compression for an optimal runtime.  It's also reasonably efficient in space, requiring only two integers for each element.

Comment: This looks awesome. I'll have a closer look later today. Thank you very much!

Comment: In your union function, you are making the bigger set the child of the smaller one.  Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: @JS1 I'm having a hard time understanding the logic behind the if/else in the union-method. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Nilzone- In order to keep the tree structure as flat as possible, when you perform the union of two trees, you want to make the smaller tree a child of the larger tree.  Imagine starting with a single node tree, and continually unioning that tree with other single nodes.  In the end, you want one root node with N other nodes as its children (a tree with depth 1).  If you make the larger tree a child of the smaller tree (which is what the code is currently doing), you end up with a tree that looks like a linked list (a tree with depth N instead of depth 1).

Comment: I updated the code with more explanatory comments.  Note that the larger/smaller doesn't impact that except that it takes an extra step to reduce the taller tree to a shorter tree for more elements.  Same step either way, just for different sets.